# Django model with User, Profile and company

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

I am trying to build an app but have a hard time to figure out my model. I have already setup the User authentication. Next:

1. Each User needs to be member of a Company (company has address info etc)
2. Each User should have a Profile
3. Invoices should be presented based on Company membership so every member gets the same page of invoices.

So the tables (models) are:

- Profile
- Invoice
- Company
- User (this already exists and is the default django User)

What would be the appropiate model relationships between those models. I would really appreciate the written model relationships like ForeignKey and ManyToMany e.d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may define relations to `Company` and `User` in `Profile`:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # Other fields here


class Invoice(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # Other fields here
```

You may want to have `ManyToManyField` as the relation to `company` based on your domain constraints.

Comment: What would be the Company model look like? I mean wouldn’t it have relations back with one of those 3?

Comment: No. Django will automatically add reverse relations to `Company`. For example we can access to invoices of a company by calling `the_company.invoice_set.all()`. Also you can set `related_name` in field descriptions which lets you use the related name instead of `invoice_set` in our example.

Comment: Much appreciated, I really needed this to go further!

Comment: How can I create a user what also creates a company with the first available Company.id? I tried this but I don't know how to create also the Company:  @receiver(post_save, sender=User)  
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

Comment: I didn't get your point. Are you going to create one object per Company, User, and Profile at once? If yes, it highly depends on your program dataflow. I mean you can create each one of User, Company, and Profile in separate views or you may want to create those three in a single view (and probably single transaction).

Comment: No problem I solved it with receiver signals post_save and post_delete